# How can I turn the number 0-8 into the 0-8th binary position in C++?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to use the integers 1-8 to represent the binary positions D0-D7.
I'm at a loss at how to transform this.  I tried taking the most significant bit, but that doesn't really work for this situation..  
Any thoughts or pointers to resources on this topic?  It's for addressing in an OLED screen.

I'm trying to think of a clever solution in C++.  I could just make a switch table, but I thought there must be a cooler way to do it with bit manipulation!

For example

```
int x = 7
y = convert(x)

if (y == 0b01000000)
print("Success!!")
```

Thank you for any and all help!!

Comment: the `<<` operator is your friend…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is bit shift - move all the bits in you variable either to left or right.
C++, among other languages uses `<<` operator to shift bits to the left. You might find other [bitwise operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/#bitwise) useful for Your application.

Using this you can replace `convert(x)` with simply `1 << (x-1)`. That changes integers 1 to 8 (inclusive) to 0th to 7th bit position (inclusive).